# Golang package import cycle not allowed

Tags: go

I have this simple project structure

```
~/project/
|--my.corp
|  |--a.go
|
|--main.go
|--go.mod
```

Content of a.go is

```
package a

// Add is cool
func Add(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

Content of main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "my.corp/a"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")

    fmt.Println(a.Add(5, 4))
}
```

and content of go.mod is

```
module my.corp/a

go 1.13
```

but when I try to use `go run main.go` in ~/project I get this:

```
import cycle not allowed
package main
        imports my.corp/a
        imports my.corp/a
```

what I am missing?

Comment: Don't use `go run` especially for a go.mod build. Use `go build` instead.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of your problem using the "multiple files" feature on https://play.golang.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file main.go is declared to be in package `my.corp/a` by the go.mod file in the same directory.  The file main.go imports `my.corp/a`, the package containing main.go.  This is a circular reference.

Note that the import path for the package containing a.go is `my.corp/a/mycorp`.

Fix by using this structure:

```
~/project/
|--a
|  |--a.go
|
|--main.go
|--go.mod
```

with this go.mod:

```
module my.corp

go 1.13
```

With this change, the package containing main.go has the import path `my.corp` and the package containing a.go has the import path `my.corp/a`.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h9jT2RKcqhH)

Comment: Thanks for help. Finaly I think I understand the whole thing around import path.*thumbs_up*